# React 'Link to' is distorting my css styling. Any way to fix it?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, e-commerce

[image][image]

I'm building an ecommerce site and when I try to add this route function my css distorts because of the link tag. When I remove Link tag the css reverts back to normal but when I put it back the styling is disorientates

[image]

Comment: Can you please include your css and the generated html with and without the `<Link />` tag? I also just want to confirm that `Link` is coming from `react-router-dom`?

Comment: yes i have Link imported correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a class to the Link component and then target that in the CSS file.

```
<Link className="link" to="/">
```

CSS then would be

```
.link .productimg {style code here}
```